# how to solve error unclosed character literal when initializing a char array in java

Tags: java

It shows me unclosed character literal error
can anyone help me

```
String sname="c:/sharan/java";
char a[]=sname.toCharArray();
for(int i=0; i< a.length;i++)
if(a[i]=='/')
    a[i]='\';
```

Comment: FYI Java's `String` class has a [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) method that can accomplish what you are doing here... `String sname="C:/sharan/java".replaceAll('/', '\\');`

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the `\`

```
a[i]='\\';
```

Otherwise, `\'` acts as an escape for the character `'`, but the character literal remains unterminated.

Answer (score 0):

`\` is an Escape Character. So you need to add additional `\`.

It means your statement should be `a[i]='\\';`

[Complete list of escape characters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)